# Meaning of any - one vs all

Tags: phrase-meaning, pronouns

Lets say someone has 10 trading cards of a fictive trading card game in his hand. He plays a card with an effect. This effect says: You discard any of your cards and this effect is activated...

Would this mean the player discards all his cards, or does it mean he can discard just one card of any type/class.

Comment: _Any of_ usually means _any one of_ - definitely not _all_.

Answer (score 2):

That rules text is ambiguous.  The key point is, "any" could reasonably mean "zero or more" or "one or more".

In other words, normal interpretations of that rule would include:

*Player discards any number of cards, **from 0 to all the cards** the player has*

*Player discards any number of cards, **from 1 to all the cards** the player has*

Usually, when you're writing rules, you want to make them as unambiguous as possible.  If we look at *Magic the Gathering* rules text, we find examples like the following:

> **One or more** target creatures become red until end of turn.

This means, the player gets to choose the number of targets, but that number cannot be zero.

> Look at the top two cards of your library, then put **any number of them** on the bottom of your library and the rest on top in any order.

This means, the player chooses the number of cards, and that number can be zero.

And in the case of *Magic the Gathering*, even though they try to make the rules text printed on the cards as unambiguous as possible, they still publish additional rules, not printed on the cards, which clarify the exact meaning of phrases like "any number".

> **107.1c** If a rule or ability instructs a player to choose “any number,” that player may choose any positive number or zero.

https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/cr107/

Comment: Thx for the response, unfortunately it's just a fictive card game / sentence where there is no further explanation. Infact, i just "invented" that back story for the readers understanding of what I mean. I care about the intuition, a native speaker would have when reading / writing a sentence like this one, with that use case of "any"

Comment: @theMahaloRecords, the answer stands: "discard any cards" is ambiguous, because "any" can be interpreted as "one or more" or "zero or more."